# using a void methods as conditions in a while loop

Tags: c#, loops

I have made a dropdown box and made a method that will change the colour of the button when clicked everytime.
however, the mouseHover colour does not go after clicking the button so I have to move the pointer from button to see the changed button colour.I am trying to make a method which will disable or change the mousehover colour after the button is clicked.

I thought of making new method which will change the mousehover colour to the buttons colour after being clicked.So i wanted to use a while loop that will run when the method to change the colour is running.

How can I do it ??

this the method to change the mousehover colour (I haven't yet figured it out)

```
 private void hidemouseHover(Button btn)
    {
        while (showbtncolor(btn))
        { 
        }
    }
```

And this the method that changes the button color after clicking

```
 private void showbtncolor(Button btn)
    {
        if (btn.BackColor != Color.FromArgb(92, 0, 230))
        {
            hideallcolour();

            btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(92, 0, 230);


        }
        else 
        {
            btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        }
    }
```

enter code here

Comment: you can't use a void-method in a while loop. in a while loop you can use a variable that can be changed inside the while-block like a boolean-variable or anything that can be used as condition. i think you should check out what events your button or controls provide and then use an event-handler

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible. 
Testing on a condition implies testing on something else than void.

You could modify you showbtncolor() method to return a boolean and determine which one of the conditions in the if-statement will return true and the other one false.
For instance, I suggest explore modifying the showbtncolor() method as follow:

```
private bool showbtncolor(Button btn)
{
    if (btn.BackColor != Color.FromArgb(92, 0, 230))
    {
        hideallcolour();

        btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(92, 0, 230);
        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I Understood how to use methods in while loops. However my problem did not solve Do you have any suggestion what i should do.

Comment: Can i use button click event in a while loop??

Comment: I don't see why you could not use a button click event (you mean invoke the event handler I guess ?) in a while loop, any loop actually.